# Debugging problem in eclipse C (Does not wait for input)

Tags: c, debugging, input

I just installed Eclipse for C/C++ and was trying to use the debugger. My program includes getting an input, the problem is that the debugger does not wait for me to put an input, and even if I do it seems to ignore it and work with a previously defined input inside or something. (The program is supposed to split long lines into smaller ones and print them).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXINPUTLENGTH 1000
#define MAXOUTPUTLENGTH 5

void myPrint(char line[], int start, int end);
int getline(char line[], int maxLength);

main()
{
    char input[MAXINPUTLENGTH];
    int len;
    int latestSpace = -1;
    while ((len = getline(input, MAXINPUTLENGTH)) > 0)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        while (len > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (len <= MAXOUTPUTLENGTH)
            {
                myPrint(input, offset, offset + len);
                len = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                for (i = 0; i < MAXOUTPUTLENGTH; i++)
                {
                    if (input[i] == ' ')
                    {
                        latestSpace = i + offset;
                    }
                }
                myPrint(input,offset,latestSpace);
                len = len - (latestSpace-offset);
                offset = latestSpace+1;


            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getline(char line[], int maxLength)
{
    int i;
    int c;
    for (i = 0; i < maxLength - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        line[i] = c;

            if (c == '\n')
        {
            line[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
    return i;
}

void myPrint(char line[], int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        putchar(line[i]);
}
```

Comment: You need to put an `int` before `main()`, and then a `void` inside the parentheses, for it to be valid.

Comment: @S.S.Anne By default the return type is int and anyway it compiles and runs fine but I seem to have a logic error (I tried what you said, but nothing changed). I can't debug because the debugger does not consider the input I put in the console.

Comment: When I run this program it consistently waits for input. Why not use `fgets` instead of `getline`?

Comment: Yes when running it, it waits for input. My problem is with the eclipse debugger, it always works with some input of length 19 (that I didn't type into the console), and I don't know how to make it take my own input, so I can trace the problem in my code. I'm still learning the language by using a textbook, so I'm not using much of the built-in functions since it was not introduced yet (and thus the exercise is required to be solved without it).

Comment: I wouldn't use Eclipse unless you are required to. I tried it once and it's hard to use. If you have a choice I suggest [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: The problem with Eclipse (and most, if not all other IDEs like Code::Blocks, Netbeans, Code, and so on) is mostly that they cannot provide a real terminal to the `stdin` of debuggees. If you *need* a terminal, use a terminal. -- In all other cases, IDEs like Eclipse are the best way to develop. Don't *fight* the tool, *work* with it.

Comment: @thebusybee is there a way to use Eclipse's debugger with a normal terminal then. Btw it seems even running it on a normal terminal behaves differently (not debugging) . In eclipse it only prints after termination.

Comment: Eclipse does not have a debugger, it talks to GDB. You can use GDB in the terminal, like S.S. Anne proposed. -- Printing to `stdout` is subject to buffering modes. Depending on the kind of output stream, the mode can be different, for example line-buffered vs. fully-buffered. Look up the documentation of `setvbuf()` for details. You might like to call `fflush()` if you're desperated.